# Visualizing year of forest loss in Hansen/UMD/Google Global Forest Change with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, visualisation

I am trying to visualize the loss of forest cover for the year 2000-2012 with the Hansen database (http://earthenginepartners.appspot.com/science-2013-global-forest/download_v1.7.html).

However, after downloading the "yearloss" layer, I only see the data for 2000 and 2012.

[image: See Image 1].

How can I visualize the annual loss?

Comment: By getting data which allows you to do so. This here doesn't seem to.

Comment: But the description of the layer is: Year of gross forest cover loss event (lossyear)
    Forest loss during the period 2000–2019, defined as a stand-replacement disturbance, or a change from a forest to non-forest state. Encoded as either 0 (no loss) or else a value in the range 1–12, representing loss detected primarily in the year 2001–2012, respectively.

Comment: Ah, there is a description hidden somewhere. Well, please re-read the last sentence of the description you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably figured this out by now, but the way I did was:

Go to layer properties, then under symbology change render type to Paletted/Unique Values, and the press classify. Then changed transparancy of the 0 value to 0% so I can see the 1 - 20 values overlayed on a map.

[image]